# Replacing strings following a certain pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series

```
2            eva.1
3            eva.2
4            eva.3
5            eva.4
           ...    
1970    normal.793
1971    normal.794
1972    normal.795
1973    normal.796
1974    normal.797
Name: Tipo Burla, Length: 1974, dtype: object
```

and I want to replace the obsevations matching "eva.1, eva.2" for just "eva" for all of them; I already tried the following:
`burla.replace('(d)','', regex=True, inplace=True)` but it's returning an output with nothing changed, as if the code didn't do anything, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: The question is what are you trying to achieve with `(d)` if your target is `eva.` which can be caught with `eva\.`?

Comment: i also tried this way and the result was the same

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:
if burla is:

```
     id      string
0     2       eva.1
1     3       eva.2
2     4       eva.3
3     5       eva.4
4  1970  normal.793
5  1971  normal.794
6  1972  normal.795
7  1973  normal.796
8  1974  normal.797
```

then replacing `eva.` by say `santan.` is done by

```
burla['string'] = burla['string'].str.replace('eva.','santan.')
```

which returns:

```
     id      string
0     2    santan.1
1     3    santan.2
2     4    santan.3
3     5    santan.4
4  1970  normal.793
5  1971  normal.794
6  1972  normal.795
7  1973  normal.796
8  1974  normal.797
```

**EDIT**

to remove the digits:

```
burla['string'] = burla['string'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

to remove the dot

```
burla['string'] = burla['string'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('.'))
```

Comment: i basically did what you did too,i think i wasn't clear on my question ,but i basically want to get rid of the ".1"  and so on, as if the value  of the observation was just "eva"

Comment: check my update. If it is what you wanted, do accept the answer. Have a nice evening!

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you so much for the help!